# I need to prepend every tr row of a table with an icon that doesn't ocupy a td cell

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-tables

I want my table to have an icon in front of every row that isnt in a td cell, so that when i hover over every row, the icon fades in. If i add it as a td to my rows, then my client id cell, which is supposed to be the first cell in every row, won't be the first anymore. So the icon would be "floating" on hover in front of every row.

CSS, html or jquery, which achieves this best and how?

I tried adding a div in front of the first td but it didn't even appear in my table. Also adding a td cell and making the background and border empty doesn't fix my problem, because my table has a box-shadow, already tried that, its not nice.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Invoice # <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></th>
        <th>Client <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></th>
        <th>Amount <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></th>
        <th>Balance <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></th>
        <th>Date <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></th>
        <th>Status <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></th>
        <th style="width: 100px">Generate Invoice</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div><!--this needs to be apart -->
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: The div there is invalid html and it's not really clear what you want to happen. Maybe add some CSS as well?

Comment: the div can be any element that should float in fron f that row, its not important what element it is, it could be a p, an a, or an i whatever. i know its not a vaid tag inside a table, but thats what i am trying to achieve

Comment: basically, i want that floating icon to show in front of every row so that when i gover over that row i see that icon and i can list options for that row. 

Here's an example from monday.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following jQuery solution.

```js
$(function() {
  $("table > tbody > tr").hover(function(e) {
    var pos = $(this).position();
    var icon_wrap = $("<div>", {
      class: "marker"
    }).appendTo("body").hide();
    var icon = $("<i>", {
      class: "fas fa-angle-down"
    }).appendTo(icon_wrap);
    icon_wrap.css({
      top: (pos.top + 6) + "px",
      left: pos.left + "px"
    }).fadeIn("fast");
  }, function() {
    $(".marker").fadeOut("fast", function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.marker {
  width: 8px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #99f;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Invoice # <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></th>
      <th>Client <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></th>
      <th>Amount <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></th>
      <th>Balance <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></th>
      <th>Date <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></th>
      <th>Status <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></th>
      <th style="width: 100px">Generate Invoice</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This uses `.hover()`, which has `in` and `out` function callbacks. You can simply add a Class and use a `:before` psudeo element using `content: ""`. With jQuery, you can use easing with `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`.

Comment: Are you able to fix the effect on the fading in and out so if you hover over many rows quickly you dont have all the icons showing up at the same time?

Comment: @UrielBitton Sure can. Just change the duration: https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/